# How do use the LayoutInflater inflater?

Tags: android

I just create the Layout design using java code only not from the XML Layout Designs.
Like the following

```
 LinearLayout llay=new LinearLayout(this);

TextView tv1=new TextView(this);
tv1.setText("New Layout");
llay.addView(tv1);
```

How do use the  LayoutInflater inflater for my LinearLayout ??? I am new to Android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `LayoutInflater` is used to get and split a layout defined via XML in your code. What I want to say is basically that you certainly don't need layout inflating if you define your layout via Java code like you've posted.

If you want to pass your `LinearLayout` as your content view then set it in your `onCreate()` method like this.

```
setContentView(llay);
```

Comment: I assume you meant `pass` not `ass`

Answer (score 4):

Create a xml layout which you want to inflate as, a parent linearlayout and Textview tv1 and use this layout as inflater in MainActivity and use setContentView(main.xml) in onCreate method;

```
LinearLayout llay=new LinearLayout(this);


LinearLayout lytContainer = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(
                    this, R.layout.inflate_xml, null);

lytContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

TextView tv1 = (TextView) lytContainer
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv1);

llay.addView(tv1);
```